# SQL: I have a table with duplicate of accnt_num that have multiple payments

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I am joining by Acct_Num column

- table1 has Acct_Num.
- table2 has pmt_cde and Acct_Num.

My goal is to serach for Acct_Num that have three (3) or more records of pmt_cde = 536.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  
    Acct_Num, COUNT (*) AS Pmt_cde
FROM tran_hist_dly  AS a
GROUP BY Acct_Num
HAVING COUNT (*) >3
 JOIN ARR_ACCT_DLY AS b
 ON a.Acct_Num = b.Acct_Num;
```

Comment: You should read [How ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, total.Total_Pmt_cde
FROM
    (
        SELECT  
            Acct_Num, COUNT (*) AS Total_Pmt_cde
        FROM tran_hist_dly
        WHERE pmt_cde = 536
        GROUP BY Acct_Num
        HAVING COUNT (*) >= 3
    ) as total INNER JOIN
    ARR_ACCT_DLY AS a ON total.Acct_Num = a.Acct_Num;
```

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
FROM
    tran_hist_dly t INNER JOIN
    ARR_ACCT_DLY AS a ON t.Acct_Num = a.Acct_Num
WHERE exists 
    (
        SELECT  
            COUNT (*) AS Total_Pmt_cde
        FROM tran_hist_dly th
        WHERE th.pmt_cde = 536
        AND   th.Acct_Num = t.Acct_Num 
        HAVING COUNT (*) >= 3
    )
```

Comment: Juan, I almos there, thanks.  in my output file, I want all the columns from table tran_hist_dly, line 5 of your code, you are not selecting Acct_Num but I want to see all other columns on that table.  I added Select *, Count... but didnt work. can you add that too?

Comment: can you also help me with the last piece? I want to show all table tran_hist_dly columns not just Acct_num? Does that make sense?

Comment: If you do that you wont have the count()

Comment: Check second query and let me know. Btw you could also upvote my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS FROM PAYMENTS_TABLE
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

Comment: actulay, I am trying to join that table with another table but i am getting syntax error: here is my code:

Comment: I am trying to join this with another table but I am getting syntax errors: here is my code:
SELECT 
 Acc_Num,
 COUNT (*) AS Payment_Cde
  FROM tran_hist_dly  AS a
HAVING COUNT (*) >3
JOIn ARR_ACCT_DLY AS b
ON a.acct_num = b.acct_num

**sorry about sluppy code, I was in a hurry, thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: Your syntax error is due to not having a GROUP BY clause. The HAVING clause is always used in conjunction with a preceding GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Also count() cannot be empty. It needs to be filled: count(1), count(*), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...
from
    (
        SELECT Acct_Num, COUNT(*) AS Payment_Cde
        FROM tran_hist_dly AS a
        GROUP BY Acct_Num
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
    ) as t /* triples */ 
    inner join
    ARR_ACCT_DLY AS aad ON aad.acct_num = t.acct_num
```

You've changed the question. Here's the way to get all the columns you want:

```
select *
from
    tran_hist_dly as thd
    inner join ARR_ACCT_DLY as aad
        ON aad.acct_num = thd.acct_num
where
        thd.pmt_cde = 536
    and thd.acct_num in (
        select Acct_Num
        from tran_hist_dly
        where pmt_cde = 536
        group by Acct_Num
        having count(*) >= 3
    )
```

Comment: great, I also want the value for pmt_cde that I am searching for to be '536', another word, acct_num that have three or more of pmt_cde = '536' . can you help please?